# Rails how to reject_if when accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Location model I have the following..

```
has_many :location_polls
```

and in the LocationPoll model, I have the following..

```
has_many :poll_locations
```

Now back in the Location model, I want to reject a location poll in case there are no poll locations. How can I do this? I tried the following and it did not work..

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location_polls, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:poll_locations].empty? }
```

My apologies if I'm missing information to help you answer the question. I didn't want to clutter up the question. Please let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: In your `reject_if` lambda, the identifier `a` points to each of your `:location_polls`, I don't know if I understood the problem but I believe you don't need that `reject_if`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to ignore any blank `:location_polls` you can use `:all_blank` which will create a proc that will reject a record where all the attributes are blank excluding any _destroy values:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location_polls, :reject_if => :all_blank
```